# Prove that $\left|\sum_{i=1}^{n} \lambda_{i}a_{i} \right|<1$

Tags: real-analysis

Consider $|a_{i}|<1$ and $\lambda_{i} \geq 0$, for $i=1,\dots,n$ and $\sum_{i=1}^{n} \lambda_{i}=1$ i want to show that $$\left|\sum_{i=1}^{n} \lambda_{i}a_{i} \right|<1$$

So, note that
\begin{align*}
\begin{aligned}
\left|\sum_{i=1}^{n} \lambda_{i}a_{i} \right| &\leq \sum_{i=1}^{n} |\lambda_{i}a_{i}| \\
&= \sum_{i=1}^{n} |\lambda_{i}||a_{i}| \\
&< \sum_{i=1}^{n} |\lambda_{i}|(1) \\
&= 1
\end{aligned}
\end{align*}

Can this be valid?

Comment: Yep. That works.

Comment: Almost correct. The strict inequality $|\lambda_{i}||a_{i}| < |\lambda_{i}|(1)$ holds only if $\lambda_i > 0$.

Comment: @MartinR Thanks for the subtlety

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the *strict* inequality
$$
\sum_{i=1}^{n} \lambda_{i}|a_{i}| < \sum_{i=1}^{n} \lambda_{i} \\
$$
one has to argue carefully because $\lambda_{i}|a_{i}| < \lambda_{i}$ holds only if $\lambda_i > 0$. One possible argument is that $\lambda_{i}|a_{i}| \le \lambda_{i}$ and the strict inequality holds for at least one index $i$ (since not all $\lambda_i$ can be zero).

Another option is to define
$$
 A = \max(|a_1|, |a_2|, \ldots, |a_n|) \, .
$$
Then $A < 1$ and
$$
\left|\sum_{i=1}^{n} \lambda_i a_i \right| 
\le \sum_{i=1}^{n} \lambda_i|a_i| \le \sum_{i=1}^{n} \lambda_i A = A < 1 \, . 
$$